# By group relative order

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like this

| ID | Week |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 11 |
| 1 | 16 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 9 |

Now, what I would like to do is to add another column to the DataFrame so that, for every ID I will mark the week's relative position. More elaborately, I would like to the mark ID's earliest week (smallest number) as 1, then the next week for the ID as 2 and so forth, where if there are two observations of the same week they get the same number.

So, in the above example I should get:

| ID | Week | Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 1 | 8 | 3 |
| 1 | 11 | 4 |
| 1 | 16 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 9 | 3 |

How could I achieve this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `df$ord <- ave(df$Week, df$ID, FUN=order)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R option using `ave` + `match`

```
transform(
  df,
  Order = ave(Week,
    ID,
    FUN = function(x) match(x, sort(unique(x)))
  )
)
```

or `ave` + `order` (thank @IRTFM for comments)

```
transform(
  df,
  Order = ave(Week,
    ID,
    FUN = order
  )
)
```

gives

```
   ID Week Order
1   1    3     1
2   1    5     2
3   1    5     2
4   1    8     3
5   1   11     4
6   1   16     5
7   2    2     1
8   2    2     1
9   2    3     2
10  2    3     2
11  2    9     3
```

---

A `data.table` option with `frank`

```
> setDT(df)[, Order := frank(Week, ties.method = "dense"), ID][]
    ID Week Order
 1:  1    3     1
 2:  1    5     2
 3:  1    5     2
 4:  1    8     3
 5:  1   11     4
 6:  1   16     5
 7:  2    2     1
 8:  2    2     1
 9:  2    3     2
10:  2    3     2
11:  2    9     3
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), Week = c(3L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA,
-11L))
```

Comment: Why not just `FUN = order)` for the `ave` illustration?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dense_rank` in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Order = dense_rank(Week)) %>% ungroup

#      ID  Week Order
#   <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     3     1
# 2     1     5     2
# 3     1     5     2
# 4     1     8     3
# 5     1    11     4
# 6     1    16     5
# 7     2     2     1
# 8     2     2     1
# 9     2     3     2
#10     2     3     2
#11     2     9     3
```